# Set GCC to generate debug symbols only for main source

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, debug-symbols

When I set the `-g` flag to GCC, it generates the debug symbols for everything, including C++ standard libraries.

But that makes the symbol list very huge.

How to set it to not generate symbols for all those libraries and headers, and only for your own source code?

Comment: Doubt that this can be achieved if by libraries and headers, you mean things included into your main executable. You just have to live with that. (And often, it does come in handy to be able to view the variables going into your `vector<X>::push_back(...)` that caused a crash, even if you don't plan on stepping through it).